# Sharing one thread pool for schedulable and non-schedulable runnables

Tags: java, threadpool

When creating a thread pool with

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
```

I can schedule tasks in it as the thread pool is of type `ScheduledExecutorService`. `ScheduledExecutorService` is a subclass of `ExecutorService`. I therefore can submit normal `Runnable`s or `Callable`s.

Is it advisable to share one single thread pool in the application or would it be better to have two separate ones?

The scheduled tasks are not that time critical and their execution on time cannot be guaranteed even with a separate thread pool if there are two many waiting threads.

If having two separate thread pools, what is a good size for them based on

- Number of tasks scheduled (you can assume that the number is constant)
- Number of CPU/cores.

Comment: I don't know about the performance or memory usage issues of ExecutorService, but I doubt they are of much concern, therefore you should strive for function separation so your code is more readable and maintainable.